# getorgchart download of previous releases

Tags: getorgchart

Is there a possibility to download previous releases of getorgchart?

The latest version has a feature which is actually not wanted.

Cheers,
Markus Maria

Comment: you can write an email to their support http://www.getorgchart.com/Support

Comment: I did, but nobody replied ... so it seems there is no interest.